# Android Chat App crashes

Tags: android

Me and some friends wrote a chat-program in Java and now we wanted to make an Android-App of it. I started today with just the basic functions. When I tried to run it, it crashes
"Unfortunately Your App crashed" or something like that.

Main.java

```
package com.Linkr.linkrandroid;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import static com.Linkr.linkrandroid.R.*;

public class Chat extends Activity {

    String username;
    Socket sock;
    BufferedReader reader;
    PrintWriter writer;
    ArrayList<String> userList = new ArrayList();
    //Boolean isConnected = false;
    TextView chatTextArea = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chatTextArea);
    TextView inputTextArea = (TextView) findViewById(id.inputTextArea);
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(layout.activity_chat);
        this.setTitle("Linkr");

    }


public class IncomingReader implements Runnable{

    public void run() {
        String[] data;
        String stream, done = "Done", connect = "Connect", disconnect = "Disconnect", chat = "Chat";

        try {
            while ((stream = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                data = stream.split(":");

                if (data[2].equals(chat)) {

                    chatTextArea.append(data[0] + ": " + data[1] + "\n");
                    //chatTextArea.setCaretPosition(chatTextArea.getDocument().getLength());

                } else if (data[2].equals(connect)){

                    //chatTextArea.removeAll();
                    //userAdd(data[0]);

                } else if (data[2].equals(disconnect)) {


                    //userRemove(data[0]);

                } else if (data[2].equals(done)) {


                    /*usersList.setText("");
                    writeUsers();
                    userList.clear();
                    */

                }

            }
        }catch(Exception ex) {
        }
    }
}

public void ListenThread() {
    Thread IncomingReader = new Thread(new IncomingReader());
    IncomingReader.start();
}
public void userAdd(String data) {
    userList.add(data);

}

public void userRemove(String data) {
    chatTextArea.append(data + " has disconnected.\n");

}

public void writeUsers() {
    String[] tempList = new String[(userList.size())];
    userList.toArray(tempList);
    /*for (String token:tempList) {

        usersList.append(token + "\n");

    }
    */

}

public void sendDisconnect() {

    String bye = (username + ": :Disconnect");
    try{
        writer.println(bye); // Sends server the disconnect signal.
        writer.flush(); // flushes the buffer
    } catch (Exception e) {
        chatTextArea.append("Could not send Disconnect message.\n");
    }

}
public void Disconnect() {

    try {
        chatTextArea.append("Disconnected.\n");
        sock.close();
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        chatTextArea.append("Failed to disconnect. \n");
    }
    isConnected = false;
    //usersList.setText("");

}
private void onClickButton(View view) {
    String nothing = "";
    if ((inputTextArea.getText()).equals(nothing)) {
        inputTextArea.setText("");
        inputTextArea.requestFocus();
    } else {
        try {
            writer.println(username + ":" + inputTextArea.getText() + ":" + "Chat");
            writer.flush(); // flushes the buffer
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            chatTextArea.append("Message was not sent. \n");
        }
        inputTextArea.setText("");
        inputTextArea.requestFocus();
    }

    inputTextArea.setText("");
    inputTextArea.requestFocus();
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.chat, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

acitivity_chat.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".Chat">
android:text = "Linkr"

<EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/inputTextArea"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/onClickButton"/>

<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Send"
        android:id="@+id/onClickButton"
        android:layout_below="@+id/chatTextArea"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/chatTextArea"/>

<EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/chatTextArea"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/inputTextArea"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
```

Thank you for helping me!
<3

Answer (score 2):

These lines are your culprits

```
TextView chatTextArea = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chatTextArea);
TextView inputTextArea = (TextView) findViewById(id.inputTextArea);
```

they can't be initialized before `setContentView()` or they will return `null` giving you a `NPE` when you try to call a method on them like `setText()`

Try changing it like so

```
TextView chatTextArea; 
TextView inputTextArea; 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(layout.activity_chat);
    chatTextArea; = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chatTextArea);
    inputTextArea; = (TextView) findViewById(id.inputTextArea);
    this.setTitle("Linkr");
```

Also, it looks like you are trying to update `UI` elements on a background thread here

```
chatTextArea.append
```

You can only update the `UI` on the `UI Thread`. I suggest looking into [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). With `AsyncTask` you can do all of your network stuff in `doInBackground()` then update your `UI` in any of its other methods. Read through the documentation carefully. It can be tricky but once you get a handle on it life is much easier.

Also, when posting on SO, if your app crashes post the logcat because that will generally make it easier  for people to help.

Comment: When I move it like this ALL chatTextAreas get an error "Cannot resolve symbol chatTextArea"

Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: Yes, look at my example again. Declare them before `onCreate()` but initialize them after `setContentView()`

Comment: But could you explain the thing with chatTextArea.append to me?

Comment: That updates a `UI` element (`TextView`). You are trying to do that in a background `Thread`and not the `UI` thread which is a no no. You need to return the values to an `Activity` method, use `runOnUiThread()`, `AsyncTask`, or something similar

Comment: Read [Painless Threading](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html)

Comment: Okay! Thank You VEEEERY much! :)